# How do I show status to users from my UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

We are creating an application(must be UWP for Microsoft app store). The application will remain running and we want to “hide” the UI from the desktop after they log in (not in taskbar).  We want to put it somewhere where they can see the status of the application and/or logout (like a VPN or Anti-virus app shows status).

We have investigated using systray (non existent in uwp), quick actions tray (seems to be for system applications), notifications (show status there, but user can remove it—looking for something like the Action Center buttons for Wifi). Our goal is to have an application running, but out of the way, with access to the status and logout functionality.  What is the Microsoft approved way?  If there is no such approved way, how have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, that's not supported in UWP.

You can however publish WPF applications to the Microsoft Store using [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter). I haven't touch it, but I've seen a few apps in the store running more elevated access than UWP and you may have the ability to control the visibility of the application's icon (ie taskbar/systemtray).

Give it a try and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, but there are some workarounds that can be used:

**1. USING [THE DISMISSED EVENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification#Windows_UI_Notifications_ToastNotification_Dismissed)** to show the notification again if user dismissed it.

**2. UWP APP WITH SYSTRAY EXTENSION**

As explained in [this blogpost](https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/), you can add a component that will create the tray icon.